# SQL Server 32-bit easysoft IB6 odbc SSIS package failing with validation error: codes 0x80004005 and 0xC0014009 when run by a sql server agent job

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, 32-bit, interbase

---

I have a SSIS package on sql server 2012.
It utilizes an easysoft odbc connection to access and optima attendance controller. In my project, I have 
`Run64BitRuntime` is false. My SQL Agent Job is also set for 32 bit run time.

I use and SSIS proxy account and it is an admin account.

I have another package running on the same server using a different odbc provider, timebersoft, but it runs without issue.

If you need more details please let me know what you need to know.

The following errors *only* occur when the package is exacuted by a sql server agent job.

> Data Flow  TAsk: Error: ODBC source failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005
>
> attnd: Error: There was an error trying to establish and Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.
>
> Data Flow Task: Error: The AquireConnection method call to the connection manager Attnd failed with error code 0xC0014009.

I have attempted to create a hello world version and every time the only thing to cause it to crash is when i try to connect to the easysoft odbc. the driver is installed (Name{Easysoft IB6 ODBC}; Version{1.00.01.70}; Company{Easysoft Limited}; File{IB6ODBC.DLL}; Date{6/5/2002}) the user is the same administrator for the successful and unsuccessful attempts

Update: July 21: 
1. Tried the installation that wasn't it. 
2. Tried Operation system(cmdline) for using 32 bit detexec.exe failed again. (double checked and the command I used did work in the cmdline)

Comment: Error code numbers don't mean much for SSIS. The text of the error message is generally much more useful. The "other" ODBC on the server that is used, is that also easysoft driver or is it something else? If you script the non-working and working jobs out (right click, script to new window) how do they differ? Has any package using easysoft ODBC ever worked on this server? Are you sure the driver has been installed and configured on the server?

Comment: So, you've never had a successful execution of any package on the server that uses the easysoft driver. I would begin ruling things out: Is the driver installed? Is the driver configured? If I create a Hello World equivalent package that uses the easysoft driver, can I run it on the server using my account? Can I run the same package using the proxy account. And so on until I discover what is amiss. Knowing *where* in that sequence of events that things break down would tell me where to spend my investigative energies

Comment: the other odbc is timberline not easysoft. the error is a validation error. this is the only time i have used easysoft on this server. the driver is installed.

Comment: Okay Thank you I'll try to figure out more information. The error log gives so very little.

Comment: That'd lead me to believe something is awry with the installation or the invocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can use our Interbase ODBC driver from SQL Server Agent or any ODBC enabled application. You will however need to install a 64-bit Interbase client that is compatable with your Interbase server before you install the Easysoft ODBC driver. This can be obtained from Embarcadero"

the issue appears to be with the software. In order to use easysoft on a 64 bit system i need the 64 bit driver properly installed.

Thank you @billinkc for pointing out the installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you must check (going from front end to back end). See what you are missing.

1. Run64BitRuntime is set to false in the project setting.
2. The same configuration setting (having Run64BitRuntime set to false) should be used for deployment.
3. If you are using an external configuration file, and that has this property, see that it is set to false.
4. SQL Server > Database Engine > SQL Server Agent > Jobs > Your job's properties > Select the step where you run the SSIS and click Edit> In the 'Execution Options' tab check 'Use 32 bit runtime'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is that file open by any chance when the SSIS runs?